# Unwanted certificate in Local Computer\SharePoint cert store

Tags: 2013, sharepoint-enterprise, sharepoint-server, ssl, certificate

One day ago my dev ShP environment stopped working, showing 500 Internal Server Error.

After analyzing the ULS logs the following error is found:

`11/13/2017 16:11:42.38 w3wp.exe (0x0C30)   0x1C1C  SharePoint Foundation   Monitoring  nasq    Medium  Entering monitored scope (Request (GET:https://XXXXconfluence.XXXXX.com:443/_layouts/15/settings.aspx)). Parent No

11/13/2017 16:11:42.40  w3wp.exe (0x0C30)   0x1C1C  SharePoint Foundation   Logging Correlation Data    xmnv    Medium  Name=Request (GET:https://XXXXconfluence.XXXXX.com:443/_layouts/15/settings.aspx)   ea7a2c9e-2403-5080-80b3-b213b527ed4e
11/13/2017 16:11:42.49  w3wp.exe (0x0C30)   0x1C1C  SharePoint Foundation   Topology    aeayb   Medium  SecurityTokenServiceSendRequest: RemoteAddress: 'http://localhost:32843/SecurityTokenServiceApplication/securitytoken.svc' Channel: 'Microsoft.IdentityModel.Protocols.WSTrust.IWSTrustChannelContract' Action: 'http://docs.oasis-open.org/ws-sx/ws-trust/200512/RST/Issue' MessageId: 'urn:uuid:7b117fc0-86d3-4234-8762-dbc3c0f0ceb7' ea7a2c9e-2403-5080-80b3-b213b527ed4e
11/13/2017 16:11:42.54  w3wp.exe (0x16E0)   0x1738  SharePoint Foundation   Topology    aeax9   Medium  SecurityTokenServiceReceiveRequest: LocalAddress: 'http://XXXX102f0f.XXXXX.com:32843/SecurityTokenServiceApplication/securitytoken.svc' Channel: 'System.ServiceModel.Channels.ServiceChannel' Action: 'http://docs.oasis-open.org/ws-sx/ws-trust/200512/RST/Issue' MessageId: 'urn:uuid:7b117fc0-86d3-4234-8762-dbc3c0f0ceb7'  ea7a2c9e-2403-5080-80b3-b213b527ed4e
11/13/2017 16:11:42.54  w3wp.exe (0x16E0)   0x1738  SharePoint Foundation   Monitoring  nasq    Medium  Entering monitored scope (ExecuteSecurityTokenServiceOperationServer). Parent No    ea7a2c9e-2403-5080-80b3-b213b527ed4e
11/13/2017 16:11:42.66  w3wp.exe (0x16E0)   0x1738  SharePoint Foundation   Claims Authentication   af3y9   Medium  STS Call Claims Windows: Successfully requested sign-in claim identity for user 'XXXXX\Sergey_Solovyev'.    ea7a2c9e-2403-5080-80b3-b213b527ed4e
11/13/2017 16:11:43.57  w3wp.exe (0x0C30)   0x1C1C  SharePoint Foundation   Monitoring  b4ly    High    Leaving Monitored Scope (SPClaimsCounterScope). Execution Time=1138.70987793141 ea7a2c9e-2403-5080-80b3-b213b527ed4e
11/13/2017 16:11:43.58  w3wp.exe (0x0C30)   0x1C1C  SharePoint Foundation   General 8nca    Medium  Application error when access /_layouts/15/settings.aspx, Error=NotTimeValid: A required certificate is not within its validity period when verifying against the current system clock or the timestamp in the signed file.     at Microsoft.SharePoint.SPCertificateValidator.SPImmutableCertificateValidator.Validate(X509Certificate2 certificate)     at Microsoft.SharePoint.SPCertificateValidator.Validate(X509Certificate2 certificate)     at Microsoft.IdentityModel.Tokens.Saml11.Saml11SecurityTokenHandler.ValidateToken(SecurityToken token)  ea7a2c9e-2403-5080-80b3-b213b527ed4e
11/13/2017 16:11:43.60  w3wp.exe (0x0C30)   0x1C1C  SharePoint Foundation   Runtime tkau    Unexpected  System.IdentityModel.Tokens.SecurityTokenValidationException: NotTimeValid: A required certificate is not within its validity period when verifying against the current system clock or the timestamp in the signed file.      at Microsoft.SharePoint.SPCertificateValidator.SPImmutableCertificateValidator.Validate(X509Certificate2 certificate)     at Microsoft.SharePoint.SPCertificateValidator.Validate(X509Certificate2 certificate)     at Microsoft.IdentityModel.Tokens.Saml11.Saml11SecurityTokenHandler.ValidateToken(SecurityToken token)   ea7a2c9e-2403-5080-80b3-b213b527ed4e
11/13/2017 16:11:43.61  w3wp.exe (0x0C30)   0x1C1C  SharePoint Foundation   General ajlz0   High    Getting Error Message for Exception System.IdentityModel.Tokens.SecurityTokenValidationException: ID4257: X.509 certificate 'E=help_desk@XXXX.com, CN=XXXXoqa.XXXXX.com, O=XXXXX, L=XXXX, S=XXXXX, C=US' validation failed by the token handler. ---> System.IdentityModel.Tokens.SecurityTokenValidationException: NotTimeValid: A required certificate is not within its validity period when verifying against the current system clock or the timestamp in the signed file.       at Microsoft.SharePoint.SPCertificateValidator.SPImmutableCertificateValidator.Validate(X509Certificate2 certificate)     at Microsoft.SharePoint.SPCertificateValidator.Validate(X509Certificate2 certificate)     at Microsoft.IdentityModel.Tokens.Saml11.Saml11SecurityTokenHandler.ValidateToken(SecurityToken token)     --- End of inner exception stack trace ---     at Microsoft.IdentityModel.Tokens.Saml11.Saml11SecurityTokenHandler.ValidateToken(SecurityToken token)     at Microsoft.IdentityModel.Tokens.SecurityTokenHandlerCollection.ValidateToken(SecurityToken token)     at Microsoft.SharePoint.IdentityModel.SPFederationAuthenticationModule.AuthenticateUser(SecurityToken securityToken)     at Microsoft.SharePoint.IdentityModel.SPFederationAuthenticationModule.SetPrincipalAndWriteSessionTokenWithOptions(SecurityToken securityToken, SPSessionTokenWriteType writeOperationType)     at Microsoft.SharePoint.IdentityModel.SPWindowsClaimsAuthenticationHttpModule.<>c__DisplayClass5.<PerformClaimsAuthenticationForUser>b__1()     at Microsoft.SharePoint.Utilities.SecurityContext.RunAsProcess(CodeToRunElevated secureCode)     at Microsoft.SharePoint.IdentityModel.SPWindowsClaimsAuthenticationHttpModule.PerformClaimsAuthenticationForUser(HttpContext context, SPFederationAuthenticationModule fam, SessionAuthenticationModule sam, WindowsIdentity windowsIdentity, SessionSecurityToken sessionSecurityToken, Boolean writeCookie)     at Microsoft.SharePoint.IdentityModel.SPWindowsClaimsAuthenticationHttpModule.AuthenticateRequest(Object sender, EventArgs e)     at System.Web.HttpApplication.SyncEventExecutionStep.System.Web.HttpApplication.IExecutionStep.Execute()     at System.Web.HttpApplication.ExecuteStep(IExecutionStep step, Boolean& completedSynchronously)   ea7a2c9e-2403-5080-80b3-b213b527ed4e`

Event Viewer shows the same:

`An operation failed because the following certificate has validation errors:

Subject Name: E=help_desk@XXXX.com, CN=XXXXqa.epam.com, O=XXXXX, L=XXXX, S=XXXX, C=US
Issuer Name: CN=XXXX, DC=XXXXX, DC=com
Thumbprint: 1588C8FDE0D6C31275EE16D96A9ED7173F29EFE7

Errors:

NotTimeValid: A required certificate is not within its validity period when verifying against the current system clock or the timestamp in the signed file.
.`

[image]

I have replaced all certificates to new ones (within the validity period), cleared certificate cache, modified IIS bindings for each website using the newly installed certificates.

Using PowerShell I've found that the certificate with the thumbprint above (*1588C8FDE0D6C31275EE16D96A9ED7173F29EFE7*) is located in **Certificate::LocalMachine\SharePoint** as shown here:  [image: cert_found]

Removing this certificate, performing iisreset as well as computer restart doesn't help - it magically appears here again.

Really don't know how to deal with this error so any help will be greatly appreciated!

Comment: are you seeing the new certificate in the store?

Comment: Yes, indeed. @via certmgr.msc

Comment: the reason, i am asking is because if you already bind the new Cert to IIS (your web application) then this error should not block you. So make sure New cert is bind to IIS and also check in pwoershell if you are getting it there as well

Comment: As I've said before, all is mapped (and in IIS too). However the errors in ULS logs persist.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The root cause was wrong STS token signing certificate.
Replacing it with a new (correct) one solved the issue.
Unfortunately, I had apparently rebooted the server without saving the POSH scripts, so steps should be:

- check STS config for certificates
- check the certificate store for such certificates
- replace the token signing certificate with a new one (self-signed or previously extracted from the server)

Answer (score 0):

There are couple of places you have to check:

- Check the if the Certificate added into the central admin, Central Admin > Security > manage trust, if old cert is still here delete it.
- Also check from the IIS, if that certificate bind to any other IIS site.
- Also remove from the IIS Server, Click on Server Name in IIS > middle pane click on Server Certificates...Make sure old certificate is not present here.
- Also check following folders from Certificate store(via MMC), Personal, Trusted certification authority and SharePoint. You can also do a [search from top level](https://technet.microsoft.com/en-us/library/cc772317(v=ws.11).aspx) and look for your old cert.

Comment: Hi, thanks but as I've said earlier, certificate was found in SharePoint cert store of Local Computer, successfully deleted, host restarted and after restart appeared again in previous location, preventing sites from loading and pulling the same error into ULS logs.  Any ideas regarding the current situation? Pls bear in mind that IIS bindings, certificate install and so on was completed of course.

Comment: I read and understand the your question, but the issue their is something still exist in the environment which is causing the issue. I would have a 2nd eye to make sure it is deleted from all the places.